# How do I load public resources with a hashtag symbol in Webpack?

Tags: webpack, vue-router, quasar

I am designing a musical application with Vue and Quasar under the Webpack bundler system. One of the requirements is to load sound files from the `public` folder. Given the musical nature of this application, some of the files contain the `#` symbol, for example, `078-F#.wav`. When I try to import this file, it becomes truncated to `078-F` and thus fails to load. How can I reconfigure my project to allow the sharp symbol in file names?

The asset files will change often and renaming them is not a practical solution.

Comment: Maybe try to escape the filename with a ```\``` like ```078-F\#.wav```. If it works for one, you could then run a regex to prefix all the `#` with a backslash.

Comment: Or even better, remove that character in your `public` directory so that you don't need to mess up with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to overcome this issue by replacing all instances of `#` with the corresponding URL character, `%23`.